# substracting elements of a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary made up of lists:

```
>>> triplets.get(k)
[[1, 3, 15], [1, 3, 13], [1, 3, 11], [1, 3, 9], [1, 3, 8], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 15]
```

and also dictionaries:

```
>>> cset1.get(k)
[set([5])]

>>> cset2.get(k)
[[1, 8], [1, 9], [1, 11]]
```

I want to delete elements of triplets which contain the element of `cset1` or both elements of `cset2`, i.e. I want to delete `[1,3,5]` which contains `[5]` and also `[1, 3, 8], [1, 3, 9], [1, 3, 11]` which contain both elements of `cset2`.

I have the following piece of code (which doesn't do anything at all):

```
CDln = len(triplets.get(k))

for ii in range(CDln):
  if cset1.get(k) in triplets.get(k)[ii] or cset2.get(k) in triplets.get(k)[ii]:
    print "delete element of triplets in location:", ii
```

I cannot figure out how to delete those elements from dictionary `triplets` (I use the `print` statement as a dummy of what I want).

Comment: Could you explain what you intend to achieve with this data structe or from where it arises? Just to avoid an X-Y-problem.

Comment: @Hyperboreus, what is an X-Y-problem?

Comment: @PaulDraper Asking a question about X, trying to solve Y.

Comment: you have to parse cset2 and cset1 to first get the values to know if you have what you need, then once you find what you need, get the key of the dictionary. then use del triplets[key] to remove it. But what you are showing looks like lists to me, not dictionaries.

Comment: It is a piece of code to calculate 1st order [one element], 2nd order [2 elements] and 3rd order [3 elements] cutsets (used in circuit reliability). I have correctly calculated 1st and 2nd order cutsets (stored in cset1 and cset2). 3rd order cutsets are the triples stored in triplets minus cset1 and cset2. I cannot figure out how to substract cset1 and cset2 from triplets (to generate cset3). I'm certain that cset1 and cset2 are dictionaries. I defined them at the start of calculations as cset1 = {} and cset2 = {}.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure if I got you right, but take a look and comment please:

```
k = 42 #whatever
triplets = {k: [[1, 3, 15], [1, 3, 13], [1, 3, 11], [1, 3, 9], [1, 3, 8], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 15]]}
cset1 = {k: [set([5])]}
cset2 = {k: [{1, 8}, {1, 9}, {1, 11}]} #changed this to sets

triplets[k] = [x for x in triplets[k] if
                all (y - set(x) for y in cset1[k]) and
                all (y - set(x) for y in cset2[k])
                ]
print(triplets[k])
```

Comment: Thank you Hyperboreus. I ran your code with no problem but when I use my data it replies with: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'set'. I don't understand why, because cset1, cset2 and triplets are defined as dictionaries.

Comment: I have converted cset2 (in order to have the same structure as in cset1) into a dict of lists of sets, and not lists of lists. See the comment in my code. But you could simple replace the last `y - set(x)` by `set(y) - set(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `ii` is, but I think this is what you want.

```
b = cset1[k]
c = cset2[k]
triplets[k] = filter(
    lambda lst:
        any(lambda x: x in b, lst) or
        any(lambda c1: all(lambda x: x in c1), c),
    triplets[k]
]
```

But:

I wonder why you have a `cset1` and `cset2`. It seems as though, you should just have `cset2`, whose value is

```
[[5], [1, 8], [1, 9], [1, 11]]
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. I ran your piece of code, it replies with: 'error: any() takes exactly one argument (2 given)'